# Rank lists based on their content similarity to the reference list

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.5

I have a **bunch of lists**, each with many `string` components.

I want to use each of these lists as reference, and rank the other lists based on their similarity to the reference list.

```
pyp1 = ['yaz', 'vur', 'mir', 'rim', 'kiss', 'pass', 'qash', 'topp', 'goz', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz']

idx1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'pass', 'sash', 'zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup']

myc2 = ['ayaz', 'aavur', 'amir', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'zash', 'zopp', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup', 'avenir']

mik1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss','gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'naz']

zach1 = ['zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'many', 'may1', 'myc2']
```

Let's say if I use **pyp1** as a reference, I want to rank remaining lists `(myc2, mik1, idx1, zach1)` based on how many same strings they have compared to the reference list.

How can I do it with new function? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to rank them by the number of matches to your reference, then you could simply use sets to calculate the intersection of your reference lists with the other lists. The length of the intersection gives you the number of matches as follows:

```
pyp1 = ['yaz', 'vur', 'mir', 'rim', 'kiss', 'pass', 'qash', 'topp', 'goz', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz']
idx1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'pass', 'sash', 'zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup']
myc2 = ['ayaz', 'aavur', 'amir', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'zash', 'zopp', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup', 'avenir']
mik1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss','gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'naz']
zach1 = ['zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'many', 'may1', 'myc2']  

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = [[len(reference.intersection(set(x))), x] for x in lists]

    for count, a_list in lists:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(count, a_list))

sort_by_matches(pyp1, [idx1, myc2, mik1, zach1])
```

This would display:

```
Matches 8 in ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'pass', 'sash', 'zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup']
Matches 5 in ['ayaz', 'aavur', 'amir', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'zash', 'zopp', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup', 'avenir']
Matches 8 in ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'naz']
Matches 4 in ['zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'many', 'may1', 'myc2']
```

---

If you want the output sorted by rank, you could sort it first by the number of matches, and then by the length of the list (shortest first), as in the example, two entries match `8`. e.g.

```
pyp1 = ['yaz', 'vur', 'mir', 'rim', 'kiss', 'pass', 'qash', 'topp', 'goz', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz']
idx1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'pass', 'sash', 'zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup']
myc2 = ['ayaz', 'aavur', 'amir', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'zash', 'zopp', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup', 'avenir']
mik1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss','gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'naz']
zach1 = ['zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'many', 'may1', 'myc2']  

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(x))), x] for x in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[1])), reverse=True)

    for count, a_list in lists:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(count, a_list))

sort_by_matches(pyp1, [idx1, myc2, mik1, zach1])
```

This would then give you:

```
Matches 8 in ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'naz']
Matches 8 in ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'pass', 'sash', 'zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup']
Matches 5 in ['ayaz', 'aavur', 'amir', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'zash', 'zopp', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup', 'avenir']
Matches 4 in ['zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'many', 'may1', 'myc2']
```

---

To determine the name, you would need to pass it with each list as follows:

```
pyp1 = ['yaz', 'vur', 'mir', 'rim', 'kiss', 'pass', 'qash', 'topp', 'goz', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz']
idx1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss', 'pass', 'sash', 'zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup']
myc2 = ['ayaz', 'aavur', 'amir', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'zash', 'zopp', 'gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'lor', 'lah', 'many', 'cup', 'avenir']
mik1 = ['yaz', 'avur', 'mir', 'riem', 'kiss','gopa', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'ariem', 'miss', 'pass', 'naz']
zach1 = ['zopp', 'gop', 'trs1', 'tsne', 'tkn', 'kaz', 'many', 'may1', 'myc2']  

def sort_by_matches(ref, lists):
    reference = set(ref)
    lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(l))), name, l] for name, l in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[2])), reverse=True)

    for matches, name, a_list in lists:
        print("Matches {} in {}".format(matches, name))

sort_by_matches(pyp1, [("idx1", idx1), ("myc2", myc2) , ("mik1", mik1), ("zach1", zach1)])
```

Giving you:

```
Matches 8 in mik1
Matches 8 in idx1
Matches 5 in myc2
Matches 4 in zach1
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin

When I run the second part of the function to rank by number of matches, I get `NameError: name 'lists' is not defined`

Comment: I tried that

`lists = sorted([[len(reference.intersection(set(x))), x] for x in lists], key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x[1])), reverse=True)`

I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: And also, how can I modify the functions, so I get 

`Matches 8 in idx1`
`Matches 5 in myc2`
`Matches 8 in mik1`
`Matches 4 in zach1`

Comment: to show all the common strings between lists, I plan to use the
`common = set(pyp1).intersection(myc2)`

Comment: You would need to pass the name of each list with the list, it is not really possible to get the variable name used to construct the list.

Comment: Thank you, its great. Would it be too much if I ask you if you can show how to add edge between my reference list pyp1 and the remaining lists, and edges show the number of matches? Using network X and matplot.pyplot

Comment: I think it would make more sense to start a new question, that way it would be clearer.